# Piezoelectric Transducer, effect of voltage amplitude vs frequency of pulsing signal?

Tags: rf, frequency, ultrasound, piezoelectricity

I am not an expert in piezoelectric transducers used for ultrasound applications so I am looking for some insight into the matter.

To extract the greatest amount of acoustic energy from the transducer is the frequency of the pulsing signal more important or is the amplitude of the pulsing signal.

For example assume there is transducer that has a resonant frequency of 12MHz is there a graph that would compare say perhaps the effect of 100V square wave centered around 10Mhz vs an 80V square wave centered at 12Mhz.

In general the question is does voltage amplitude play a greater role in a generating a stronger response from the transducer or is the resonant frequency of the applied signal more important?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the [Q](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor) of the transducer coupled to the medium.. it's not a characteristic of transducer alone. If the Q is very high the response will be very sharp around the resonant frequency.

Comment: do you have a resource where I can read further about the behaviour of transducers and perhaps a graph that shows the effect of frequency with a given amplitude vs a the effect of amplitude with a given frequency.

Comment: Since you're apparently interested in medical ultrasound, a reference such as [this](https://www.inkling.com/read/essential-physics-medical-imaging-jerrold-bushberg-3rd/chapter-14/14-3-ultrasound-transducers) may be useful.

Comment: It will totally depend on the transducer.  The manufacturer should supply a response vs frequency curve.